# CSS : Overlaying divs on top of each other using flexbox syntax(vw, vh)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

```css
.thumbnail{
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border:1px solid gray;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    min-width: 10vw;
    min-height: 40vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.thumbnail_img{
 width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1000;
}

p.caption_heading{
 font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-size: 20px;
  
}
span.caption_desc{
 font-size:15px;
 color: gray;
}

.caption{
 flex-grow: 1;
 z-index: 1000;
 background-color: white; 
}

.thumbnail_footer{
 padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 1000;
}


.description{
    position: absolute;
    width: 12.7vw; /* as image */
    height: 40vh; /* as image */
    line-height: 200px; /* as image */
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    font-weight: bold;
    z-index: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(252, 111, 27, 0.0);
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction : column;
}


div.description_heading {
 font-size: 20px;
  /* font-size: calc(4vw + 4vh + 2vmin); */
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 2em;
}

div.description_desc {
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 2em;
}

.thumbnail:hover .description {
 position:absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    display:block;
    background-color: rgba(252, 111, 27, 0.9);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="flex_body" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-between; ">
<div class="thumbnail">
     <div class="thumbnail_img">
         <img class="thumbnail_img" src="./resources/img/size_minmuri1.jpg" alt="...">
         </div>
         <div class="caption">
           <p class="caption_heading">Item name<br/>
           <span class="caption_desc">Item description</span></p>
         </div>
         <div class="thumbnail_footer">
           <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Read</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a>      
         </div>
         <!-- overlay item  -->
          <div class="description" href="#">
            <div class="description_heading"><br>_____<br>Item name<br>_____</div>
            <div class="description_desc">Item description</div>
            
          </div>
          <!-- overlay item  -->
       </div>
</div>
```

I've been working to make an effect when user over their mouse over a div, it shows color overlay. It is simple effect. However the problem is I used flex, vw and vh, because I wanted to make responsive site. So when I made divs' size perfectly match each other, once browser size become different than it does not match anymore. I tried to find any examples on the internet but those are usually fixed size with px or position. I would like to know if there is a way to overlay color div on another div. If there is no solution, I guess I have to rebuild site into non-responsive.

Here is HTML

```
<div class="thumbnail">
  <div class="thumbnail_img">
    <img class="thumbnail_img" src="./resources/img/size_minmuri1.jpg" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
      <p class="caption_heading">Item name<br/>
          <span class="caption_desc">Item description</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail_footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Read</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a>      
    </div>
    <!-- overlay item  -->
    <div class="description" href="#">
        <div class="description_heading"><br>_____<br>Item name <br>_____</div>
        <div class="description_desc">item description</div>        
    </div>
    <!-- overlay item  -->
</div>
```

So When user hover their mouse over thumbnail div, description div should be appear and cover whole thumbnail div.

Here is CSS

```
.thumbnail{
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   border:1px solid gray;
   background-color: white;
   border-radius: 5px;
   margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
   min-width: 10vw;
   min-height: 40vh;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   cursor: pointer;
   z-index: 1000;
 }

.thumbnail_img{
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   z-index: 1000;
}

p.caption_heading{
   font-weight: bold;
   line-height: 1em;
   font-size: 20px;
}
span.caption_desc{
   font-size:15px;
   color: gray;
 }

.caption{
   flex-grow: 1;
   z-index: 1000;
   background-color: white; 
}

.thumbnail_footer{
   padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
   background-color: white;
   z-index: 1000;
 }


 .description{
   background:rgba(252, 111, 27, 0.75);
   text-align:center;
   padding:45px 0 66px 0;
   opacity:0;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease;
  }


 div.description_heading {
   font-size: 20px;
   font-weight: bold;
   line-height: 2em;
 }

div.description_desc {
   font-size: 15px;
   line-height: 2em;
 }

.thumbnail:hover .description {
   opacity: 1; 
  }
```

Comment: So is the `.description` element hidden at first? Then it shows when you mouse over the `.thumbnail`?

Comment: `vh` and `vw` units are always relative to the *viewport* (hence the names: *viewport height* and *viewport width*). So even though you are able to match the `vh` and `vw` dimensions to your div at one screen size, that layout will fall apart when you re-size the screen, because `vh` / `vw` have no association with the div.

Comment: @JakeParis yes.

Comment: @Michael_B It means that It is not good choice to use vw and vh for this effect? So I guess only px will work for this effect?

Comment: Can you post a working demo? Maybe jsfiddle.net or codepen.io.

Comment: Well, it's hard to answer that without really seeing the effect you want. Could you paste a screenshot or something?

Comment: @Michael_B I added snippet.

Comment: @JakeParis I added snippet, you can see what I made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You made many mistake of your code.

**You didn't set left and right for absolute position**. If your position is `absolute` you should be set `left` `right` `top` and `bottom` `css` property. If you want to set `hover` effect for only `image` then you need to set `image` inside the `position` `relative` `div`. Then your `hover` content will placed with `image`. `width` and `height` will set `100%` if you set `fixed` `width` it will not `responsive`.

**I fixed your problem except description inside content.**

> Now on your own.

```css
.thumbnail{
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border:1px solid gray;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    min-width: 10vw;
    min-height: 40vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: relative;
}

.thumbnail_img{
 width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: relative;
}

p.caption_heading{
 font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-size: 20px;
  
}
span.caption_desc{
 font-size:15px;
 color: gray;
}

.caption{
 flex-grow: 1;
 z-index: 1000;
 background-color: white; 
}

.thumbnail_footer{
 padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 1000;
}


.description{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; /* as image */
    height: 100%; /* as image */
    line-height: 200px; /* as image */
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    font-weight: bold;
    z-index: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(252, 111, 27, 1);
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction : column;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}


div.description_heading {
 font-size: 20px;
  /* font-size: calc(4vw + 4vh + 2vmin); */
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 2em;
}

div.description_desc {
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 2em;
}

.thumbnail:hover .description {
 /*position:absolute;*/
    z-index: 1000;
    /*display:block;*/
    background-color: rgba(252, 111, 27, 0.9);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="flex_body" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-between; ">
<div class="thumbnail">
     <div class="thumbnail_img">
         <img class="thumbnail_img" src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt="...">
            <div class="description" href="#">
            <div class="description_heading"><br>_____<br>Item name<br>_____</div>
            <div class="description_desc">Item description</div>
            
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="caption">
           <p class="caption_heading">Item name<br/>
           <span class="caption_desc">Item description</span></p>
         </div>
         <div class="thumbnail_footer">
           <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Read</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a>      
         </div>
         <!-- overlay item  -->
          
          <!-- overlay item  -->
       </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.